# is it violate 2NF?

Tags: sql, join, one-to-many, database-normalization

My table

**book**

- PK  ID           INT
- pfK langID       INT
- title            VARCHAR
- description      MEDIUMTEXT
- releaseYear      YEAR
- chaptersPrice    DOUBLE
- thumbnail        BLOB

Where
pfk - Primary-Foreign Key;

{ID, langID} - PK;

chaptersPrice - price of each chapter of book. Example:

BookName1:

- chaptersPrice=2

BookName2:

- chaptersPrice=3

I think in this table some attributes are functionally dependent on the part of primary key (ID):

{ID} ->  {releaseYear}

{ID} ->  {chaptersPrice}

{ID} ->  {thumbnail}

Should I implement it like this

**book**

- PK  bookID
- pfK langID
- title
- description

**book_attrs**

- PK ID
- FK bookID
- releaseYear
- chaptersPrice
- thumbnail

Then book and book_attrs have "one-to-many" relationship

Comment: Right now you are just asking for us to rewrite a textbook with a bespoke tutorial. You don't connect what you "think" with answering. Please see [ask], hits googling 'stackexchange homework' & the voting arrow mouseover texts. Show the steps of your work following a textbook/reference with justification & ask 1 specific researched non-duplicate question re the first place you are stuck. Quote the definitions, theorems, algorithms & heuristics you are relying on. All the steps are also SO faqs. Google with & without 'site:stackoverflow.com'.

Comment: Are you trying to say that {ID, langID} is the PK? You are not clear. Use words or universally understood notation. Don't use notation that you haven't explained. Also you don't mean "have a relationship with", you mean "are functionally determined by". PS If you have a row from book_attrs, what book does it tell you about?

Comment: I apologize for the incorrectly constructed question. Yes Book table has {ID, langID} composite primary key.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Some considerations may depend on your use-case / domain model.

- releaseYear of a book typically does not change (in simple cases), so it could be in BOOK table.
- From a 'book store' perspective, 'price' could be in a different table, as that would be updated based on market conditions.

Comment: Thanks a lot! In fact, the `price` belongs to the chapters of the books, not the book. But I didn't add the price to the `chapter` table because all chapters in the same book have the same price. And in this way, I can sort the `book` by `price`. Maybe, I have to return `price` to `chapter` table?

Comment: Oh I see ..  usecase is sellling by CHAPTERS and not whole book.  If all chapters of A-BOOK is sameprice -> current scheme may be ok.  If ANY-CHAPTER in ANY-BOOK is going to be same price --> 'chapterprice' is a global setting for the whole system.